# Redux store with Math formulas as functions

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, redux

While writing an engineering application with a React Redux framework we have come across an issue of having a database of products that have functions to work out their load capacities and other properties. I know it is not a good idea to load the functions into the store and retrieving the functions from another location in the reducer breaks purity and makes the reducer much harder to test.

Is their any React Redux way of supplying the reducers with the database of product functions as a parameter, or similar, without putting them in the store and without breaking purity?

**Edit:**

Each of the products have functions that might describe for example the relationship between jack extension and load capacity. This relationship is usually non-linear and has a graph that will relate the capacity over its extendable range. We have used curve fitting tools to match these graphs to functions over their range. I would like to be able to use these functions in a reducer such that when someone selects a product and extension we can obtain the capacity and check its suitability against other calculated loads in the state.

Comment: Can you describe the details of your use case? If you have some general helper functions I think it's kind of a "single source". But if every database record has a unique function, that will not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Yes, including non-serializable items such as functions in actions or the store state is definitely discouraged, on the grounds that it will generally break time-travel debugging.  ***However***, if that is not a concern for you, it *is* something you could do.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-non-serializable and http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#actions-string-constants .
- Another approach would be to keep the math functions in a lookup table, and include a function name in the action that can be used to look up the correct math function for use in the reducer
- A third option is to do more of the work in thunk action creators, and put the results of the calculations into the action.

Comment: Currently considering option 2. I was initially hesitant as it would make the reducer impure but I then realized that if i curry the database of functions into the reducer then the it would still be testable and not as impure? Something like `createStore(reducerWithDatabase(productDatabase))`. `var reducerWithDatabase = (productDatabase) => (state, action) => state`

Comment: That's one way to do it, I guess.  That said, having the reducer function call other functions as part of the process doesn't make it "impure", as long as those functions are themselves pure and don't have side effects.  Math functions would seem likely to be pure functions, so calling them to do work should be fine.